# Explicit Lyrics in Songs - Warning?

Tags: discussion

Some songs that get linked have explicit lyrics, should we warn in our post that the song has these lyrics or does it not matter?

Comment: I'd say people should grow some thicker skin if they seriously have a problem with explicit lyrics. Or are the actually workplaces where you get in trouble for opening a page containing explicit lyrics but not for browsing such lyrics pages in the first place?

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Don't forget that people of all ages are music fans, and you never know the age of someone who might be browsing these links.  I'd prefer SE be known as a "family friendly" site, and I'm sure Jeff and Joel would too.

Comment: tbh, most kids learn much worse things than explicit lyrics in school nowadays (and it's not like they wouldn't click it because it's labelled explicit - it probably makes it more interesting)

Comment: Every music fan should be immunized against explicit lyrics ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Most music you buy will have an explicit tag to show when a song or album is explicit [as seen in this album off Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011TSXCZ6) which is not a bad idea to include if the song is explicit.

I would think just putting and explicit tag at the end of the hyperlink would be enough as such: [Lyrics here [Explicit]](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250/explicit-lyrics-in-songs-warning). For consistency sake and so the user knows what they are getting into.

Comment: Would creating [tag:explicit] be a bad thing? Sometimes, for identification, some components may be explicit. In this example, it is the lyrics, but it could be the title or even the videoclip/movie where the music is present.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I'd say no as that's really not useful for grouping the questions we get themselves.

Comment: Some people prefer explicit stuff. For example, a question about Eminem can't be a clean version. Nobody listens the clean version. Having [tag:explicit] would fix that. But there are a ton other situations where the tag would be not-so-good

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel But they like Eminem who's music is typically explicit, but it does not mean that they will like **all** explicit music. On the scale of all things you could base your taste in music on I doubt this is high on anyone's list.

Comment: I'm just giving a possibility. I'm not giving a decisive answer. Maybe a meta about it would be better than us debating in the comment section on a question that has nothing to do with it?

Comment: I'd say Dom's answer is sound, and if anyone wants to get a little editing extra credit it wouldn't be a bad idea to go back and add that to any videos/links that need it.  As far as tags go, I don't see an 'explicit' tag being helpful.